# Vertically centered nested flex box

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve a simple layout with three vertical sections:

1. Small header on top of the page.
2. Main content, expanded if necessary so that the footer remains at the bottom of the page.
3. Footer at the bottom of the page.

The main content section should be further divided in two sections: a very small form with an input box and a button and a 5-row-max table showing some tabular data. The table should take up as much vertical space as needed, an the small form should be centered in the remaining vertical space.

I've tried using flex boxes but there is something I am doing wrong; I cannot manage to vertically center the tiny form in the available space. This is a simplified version of what I've done so far (best viewed in full screen):

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  min-height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
}

main {
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

main>form {
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>header</header>
  <main>
    <form>
      <h1>Form with inputs</h1>
      <label>Inputs</label>
      <input type="text">
      <button>Button</button>
    </form>
    <div>
      <h1>Other content</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

I have tried multiple combinations of `justify-content`, `align-content`, `align-items` and `align-self` but the more I try, the less I seem to understand what I am doing :-(

Can anyone who does, provide me with any hints as to what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: If I could use fixed heights for some elements, I might do something like this (which also illustrates what I am after, better viewed in full screen):

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
      
html {
  height:100%;
}
  
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
}

header {
  height:40px;
  background-color:#E6ECC1;
}

main {
  height:calc(100% - 80px);
  background-color:#dfd;
}

h1 {
  margin:0;
  padding:10px 0;
}

main>form {
  height:calc(100% - 150px);
  background-color:#C1E4EC;
}

main>form:before {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

main>form>div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
  text-align: center;
}

main>div {
  padding:0 20px;
  height:150px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:40px;
}

footer {
  position:absolute;
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:#fdd;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>header</header>
  <main>
    <form>
      <div>
        <h1>Form with inputs</h1>
        <label>Inputs</label>
        <input type="text">
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div>
      <h1>Other content</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

I thought I would be able to implement this more cleanly using two nested flex boxes; an outer one providing room for the header at the top, the footer at the bottom and a mid section that can grow to fill all available space in between, and an inner one dividing the outer mid section into two; a bottom one with a constant but unknown height and a top one taking up all remaining space in the mid section. The content of this block, much smaller than the available area when the page is viewed in a large display, should be centered both horizontally and vertically in the available area.

When I only use an outer flex box (the `<body>` element in my original snippet) the content is centered vertically between the header and the footer. But when I try to split the mid section (the `<main>` element in my original snippet), the form is pushed upwards. It is as if the height of the `flex:1` element in the outer box were not available to its children elements.

Thank you very much, have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Your centering (justify/align-content) isn't inherited so you have to restate it for each flex-container.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
header {
  background: green
}
main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: pink;
}
main>form {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>header</header>
  <main>
    <form>
      <h1>Form with inputs</h1>
      <label>Inputs</label>
      <input type="text">
      <button>Button</button>
    </form>
    <div>
      <h1>Other content</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you @Paulie_D, although that is not quite what I am after. What I am trying is for the orange section to expand taking up all that available pink space (pushing the "Other content" down) while keeping the "Form with inputs" group centered inside the orange area. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I thank everyone who answered, although the answers did not quite do what I was trying to do. In the end, I have managed what I was after by wrapping the form inside an extra div to which I applied the flex attributes:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  background-color: #fdd;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div.form {
  background-color: #dfd;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

div.other {
  background-color: #fdb;
  padding: 0 10vw;
}

footer {
  background-color: #ddf;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>header</header>
  <main>
    <div class="form">
      <form>
        <h1>Form with inputs</h1>
        <label>Inputs</label>
        <input type="text">
        <button>Button</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="other">
      <h1>Other content</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

I hope this can help someone else with a similar problem in the future!

Comment: Hmmm... I've just scrolled the snippet down :-(

Answer (score -1):

1. Get rid of `align-items: center;` because it turns block elements into inline-blocks, use `text-align: center` instead.

[image: flexbox align items center problems]

2. both `html` and `body` would require a defined `height` of `100%`
3. If you want the `form` inside `main` to take most space, then simply apply `flex: 1` to it.

Working simplified demo:

```css
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; text-align: center;}

body { width: 100%; display:flex; flex-direction:column; }

header { padding: 1em; background: lightblue; }

footer { padding: 1em; background: gray; }

main { flex:1; display:flex; flex-direction:column; background: lightyellow; overflow: auto;}

main > form { border-bottom:1px dashed gold; flex:1; }

#data { padding: 1em; }

main ul  { margin: 0; padding: 0; display: inline-block }
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>
  <form>
    <h1>Form with inputs</h1>
    <label>Inputs</label>
    <input type="text">
    <button>Button</button>
  </form>
  <div id="data">
    <h1>Other content</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/hLse4wa7/

Comment: I appreciate your answer, Aziz, although I am not sure I understand your suggestions. 1) I thought the inlineness and/or blockness of the children was irrelevant once the container is declared as display:flex. 2) I am explicitly using a viewport-based height (100vh). That is not inherited from any ancestor and thus it doesn't need to be declared in any ancestor. Or does it? 3) But I want the form to take most space, not the table; that is why I applied it to the form. Thank you nevertheless for the time taken to help me. Have a good day!

Comment: @CarvoLoco Hello. **(1)** Apparently if you set `align-items: center`, the box model's width will be reduced to content (not block) and yes, if you try to set any `display` value it will not work. This has to do with the way the flex model works, I'm not sure exactly why but you can try it yourself (I also attached picture of how it looks in my answer). **(2)** You are right about this. `100vh` will be sufficient however you might want to check browser compatibility. **(3)** that was a misunderstanding, updated my answer. Have a nice day as well!